# Spring boot security console/command line application

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

Spring boot tutorials generally explain how to secure a web application based on spring boot but not a console/command line application (accessed from a spring-boot-starter-remote-shell).

For a web application, we just need to extends from **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**, then to override some methods.

Is there an equivalent class to extends for a console/command line application? If not, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Interesting one. There is no default class to extend for configuration, although you can reuse all of the backend beans. How would you supply the username/password? You can use the different `SecurityBuilder` implementations for configuration, as long as you don't touch the webbased ones :).

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate what you are trying to secure with spring security in your console app.

Answer (score 0):

According to [spring-boot reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-connecting-to-the-remote-shell)

> If your application is using Spring Security, the shell will use the same configuration by default.

If you want Crsh to use your authentication manager [you have 2 options](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/CrshAutoConfiguration.html)

> This authentication method will get enabled if shell.auth is set to spring or if no explicit shell.auth is provided and a AuthenticationManager is available.

If you need find grained access decision management in Csrh you can also define a `AccessDecisionManager` bean named `"shellAccessDecisionManager"`.

See [`CrshAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/CrshAutoConfiguration.java)

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
    @Qualifier("shellAccessDecisionManager")
    private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;
```